# is cin is logic 1 or 0?

Tags: c++, while-loop

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int x,y;
    while(cin)
        cin>>x>>y;
        cout<<"YES";

}
```

1. here for which input it will print out "YES"?
2. is cout is logic 1 or 0?

Comment: `#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;` - *No*, no, no. Don't *ever* do that.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool

Comment: @JesperJuhl That comment is not useful as it is now because it does not offer an alternative. It isn't obvious to new developers what these lines do so it isn't obvious what the alternatives are. If you added a link to the questions explaining the problem ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)) it would be allow OP to understand the problem and to know what else they can do instead. Edit : Had the wrong link...

Comment: *Please* read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/5910058)

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I just posted a link to a question that's answered with the *why*.

Answer (score 4):

This will print "YES" for *any* input (except for an infinite stream of valid input, in which case it'll run forever and never print anything).

1. You forgot braces for your loop, so the `cout` statement is not actually in the loop.
2. Your `cout` is in *no way* conditional on the values you read in.

Comment: *"This will print "YES" for any input."*. Not for **infinite** valid input ;-)

Comment: @Jarod42 updated answer to address that corner case.